# hive performance union all

Tags: performance, hive, union

I have multiple files, combining them through single file using Hive `union all`, now the `union all` query joins more than 10 Hive tables, and is very slow. Each individual `union all` query has one or more join condition as well.

My expected end result is also required to be grouped by primary key, e.g:

```
table 1 

key1|val1|val2|..

table 2

key1|val10|val11|..

insert overwrite <temptable>
select key, output_string from
(select key, concat (col1,col2,..) from table 1 where <join conditions>
union all
select key, concat(col10,col11,..) from table 2 where <join conditions>
..
)
cluster by key;
```

`union all` will combine above two tables, i'm using cluster by key to produce desired result. The performance of hive is extremely slow, what are the other alternatives?

Comment: I see @veeraB's answer, which looks authoritative.  I think the first question to ask is how long each of the individual queries is taking -- any one that is long-running will affect the whole `union`ed chain.  The next question is, can Hive parse the query in such a way as to run each of the queries in parallel, which can be observed perhaps by `EXPLAIN` or just by watching as it executes; if not, the `hive.optimize.union.remove` setting might be an option to consider.

Answer (score 1):

Note this option:

```
hive.optimize.union.remove
Default Value: false
Added In: Hive 0.10.0 with HIVE-3276
```

Whether to remove the union and push the operators between union and the file sink above union. This avoids an extra scan of the output by union.

This is independently useful for union queries, and especially useful when `hive.optimize.skewjoin.compiletime` is set to `true`, since an extra union is inserted.

The merge is triggered if either of `hive.merge.mapfiles` or `hive.merge.mapredfiles` is set to `true`.

If the user has set `hive.merge.mapfiles` to `true` and `hive.merge.mapredfiles` to `false`, the idea was that the number of reducers are few, so the number of files anyway is small.

However, with this optimization, we are increasing the number of files possibly by a big margin. So, we merge aggressively.

Comment: Thanks Tom and veeraB. hive.optimize.skewjoin.compiletime should do the trick. The union all queries were earlier spawning 100+ map-reduce jobs but I made changes to remove some of unnecessary joins and now it is down to 12+ mr jobs.